# Problemas con carousel de Bootstrap

Tags: html, html5, bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-carousel

Estoy haciendo una página web para un amigo y quería añadir un carousel con Bootstrap pero no consigo que se vea y no soy capaz de encontrar ningún error en el código. Lo dejo a continuación para ver si alguien me puede explicar que está mal.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".carousel").carousel()
  var altura = $('.menu').offset().top;
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > altura) {
      $('.menu').addClass('menu-fixed');
    } else {
      $('.menu').removeClass('menu-fixed');
    }
  });
  $("#conciertos").mouseover(function() {
    $("#conciertos").css("background-color", "#800000");
  });

  $("#entrevistas").mouseover(function() {
    $("#entrevistas").css("background-color", "#800000");
  });

  $("#videoclips").mouseover(function() {
    $("#videoclips").css("background-color", "#800000");
  });

  $("#canciones").mouseover(function() {
    $("#canciones").css("background-color", "#800000");
  });

  $("#sobreMi").mouseover(function() {
    $("#sobreMi").css("background-color", "#800000");
  });

  $(".listaArriba").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".listaArriba").css("background-color", "#B22222");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <body>
      <header class="headerEnd">
        <div class="cabecera">
          <a href="endi.html"><img src="endikaHeader.png" id=titulua></a>
        </div>
      </header>
      <header class="header">
        <div class="menu" id="menu">
          <nav class="top-menu">
            <ul class="navigation">
              <li class="listaArriba" id="conciertos">CONCIERTOS
              </li>
              <li class="listaArriba" id="entrevistas"><a href="endi.html">ENTREVISTAS</a></li>
              <li class="listaArriba" id="videoclips"><a href="endi.html">VIDEOCLIPS</a></li>
              <li class="listaArriba" id="canciones"><a href="endi.html">CANCIONES</a></li>
              <li class="listaArriba" id="sobreMi">;<a href="endi.html">SOBRE MI</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>

        <div class="seccion1">
          <img id="imagen0" class="img_carrusel " src="http://maaproject.org/maap/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/TambopataSept092016_ZOOMA_span_v2-1500x750.jpg" alt="Aqui pondria algo">
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
          <ul class="navigationFoot">
            <a href="https://es-es.facebook.com/"><img src="IconosRedes/iconoFacebook.png"></a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com?hl=es"><img src="IconosRedes/iconoInsta.png"></a>
            <a href="https://soundcloud.com"><img id="soundcloud" src="IconosRedes/soundcloud.png"></a>
          </ul>
        </div>


        <div class="carousel">
          <div id="carousel-ejemplo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#carousel-ejemplo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#carousel-ejemplo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            </ol>

            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
              <div class="item active">
                <img src="https://imgs.mongabay.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/20/2016/10/01175857/TambopataSept092016_ZOOMC_v2-1500x750.jpg" alt="...">

                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h3>Endi</h3>
                  <p>Y su videoclip</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <img src="http://maaproject.org/maap/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/TambopataSept092016_ZOOMA_span_v2-1500x750.jpg" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h3>Endi</h3>
                  <p>Y su primer videoclip</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!--controles-->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-ejemplo" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previo</span>
            </a>

            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-ejemplo" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Siguiente</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </body>
```

PD: He omitido algunos nombres, títulos y enlaces para mantener la privacidad de mi amigo. Tambén he quitado las etiquetas  porque no aportaban nada.

Comment: Te he metido el codigo en un snippet. . Tambien añadi el CDN de bootstrap. Cambia las imagenes por alguna que podamos ver. Un saludo

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. He hecho ya el cambio, he metido 2 imágenes en el carousel pero a la hora de ejecutar el código me salen las imágenes una debajo de la otra en vez de como si fuera un carousel y no entiendo donde está el fallo. He pensado que igual podría ser la versión de Bootstrap o algo del estilo.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problemas con el carousel de Bootstrap](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/115998/problemas-con-el-carousel-de-bootstrap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que tu problema es simplemente que te falta llamar los estilos de `bootstrap`, ejecuté tu código en mi entorno local importando la hoja de estilos `css` de `bootstrap` y funciona perfectamente, acá te dejo el ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".carousel").carousel()
  var altura = $('.menu').offset().top;
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > altura) {
      $('.menu').addClass('menu-fixed');
    } else {
      $('.menu').removeClass('menu-fixed');
    }
  });
  $("#conciertos").mouseover(function() {
    $("#conciertos").css("background-color", "#800000");
  });

  $("#entrevistas").mouseover(function() {
    $("#entrevistas").css("background-color", "#800000");
  });

  $("#videoclips").mouseover(function() {
    $("#videoclips").css("background-color", "#800000");
  });

  $("#canciones").mouseover(function() {
    $("#canciones").css("background-color", "#800000");
  });

  $("#sobreMi").mouseover(function() {
    $("#sobreMi").css("background-color", "#800000");
  });

  $(".listaArriba").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".listaArriba").css("background-color", "#B22222");
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <body>
      <header class="headerEnd">
        <div class="cabecera">
          <a href="endi.html"><img src="endikaHeader.png" id=titulua></a>
        </div>
      </header>
      <header class="header">
        <div class="menu" id="menu">
          <nav class="top-menu">
            <ul class="navigation">
              <li class="listaArriba" id="conciertos">CONCIERTOS
              </li>
              <li class="listaArriba" id="entrevistas"><a href="endi.html">ENTREVISTAS</a></li>
              <li class="listaArriba" id="videoclips"><a href="endi.html">VIDEOCLIPS</a></li>
              <li class="listaArriba" id="canciones"><a href="endi.html">CANCIONES</a></li>
              <li class="listaArriba" id="sobreMi">;<a href="endi.html">SOBRE MI</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>

        <div class="seccion1">
          <img id="imagen0" class="img_carrusel " src="http://maaproject.org/maap/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/TambopataSept092016_ZOOMA_span_v2-1500x750.jpg" alt="Aqui pondria algo">
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
          <ul class="navigationFoot">
            <a href="https://es-es.facebook.com/"><img src="IconosRedes/iconoFacebook.png"></a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com?hl=es"><img src="IconosRedes/iconoInsta.png"></a>
            <a href="https://soundcloud.com"><img id="soundcloud" src="IconosRedes/soundcloud.png"></a>
          </ul>
        </div>


        <div class="carousel">
          <div id="carousel-ejemplo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#carousel-ejemplo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#carousel-ejemplo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            </ol>

            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
              <div class="item active">
                <img src="https://imgs.mongabay.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/20/2016/10/01175857/TambopataSept092016_ZOOMC_v2-1500x750.jpg" alt="...">

                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h3>Endi</h3>
                  <p>Y su videoclip</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <img src="http://maaproject.org/maap/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/TambopataSept092016_ZOOMA_span_v2-1500x750.jpg" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h3>Endi</h3>
                  <p>Y su primer videoclip</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!--controles-->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-ejemplo" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previo</span>
            </a>

            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-ejemplo" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Siguiente</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </body>
```

Comment: Si tenías razón. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta te invito a que la marques como aceptada para que los futuros desarrolladores sepan que fue la solución indicada, además te invito a que te hagas el [tour] si no lo has hecho para que entiendas el funcionamiento básico del sitio, otra información importante que podrías leer es [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) saludos!

Comment: Perfecto, ya la he marado como aceptada. Ahora le echaré un vistazo al recorrido para ver el funcionamiento.
Saludos y gracias.