# Problemas con el carousel de Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel

Estoy teniendo un problema con el carousel y no sé que tengo que cambiar para solucionarlo. El problema es que el carousel coge las dos fotos bien pero no hace slide bien en las dos fotos.

Se tarda en la primera foto unos `4 segundos` y luego en la segunda foto no tarda más que `medio segundo` antes de volver a la primera foto. Este último cambio lo hace sin slide, directamente.

Adjunto el código para ver si podéis decirme que está mal, ya que yo no veo nada o se me escapa el error:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".carousel").carousel();
var altura = $('.menu').offset().top;
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > altura) {
        $('.menu').addClass('menu-fixed');
    } else {
        $('.menu').removeClass('menu-fixed');
    }
});
$("#news").mouseover(function() {
    $("#news").css("background-color", "#800000");
    $("#a").css("color", black);
});

$("#conciertos").mouseover(function() {
    $("#conciertos").css("background-color", "#800000");
});

$("#videos").mouseover(function() {
    $("#videos").css("background-color", "#800000");
});

$("#songs").mouseover(function() {
    $("#songs").css("background-color", "#800000");
});

$("#lyrics").mouseover(function() {
    $("#lyrics").css("background-color", "#800000");
});

$("#store").mouseover(function() {
    $("#store").css("background-color", "#800000");
});

$(".listaArriba").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".listaArriba").css("background-color", "#B22222");
});

});
```

```css
.headerEnd {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #000000;
height: 100px;
}

#fotoEndi {
margin-left: 100px;
}

@font-face {
font-family: "TituloEndi";
src: url("GameofBrush.ttf");
}

a:link {
text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
color: #000000;
}

#nombreEndi {
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
top: 50%;
color: #8B0000;
font-family: "TituloEndi";
font-size: 40px;
}

.header {
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

.menu {
height: 37px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #B22222;
color: #333;
text-align: center;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
}

.wrapper {
height: 2000px;
width: 100%;
padding-top: 20px
}

.menu-fixed {
position: fixed;
z-index: 1000;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #999;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 25px;
width: 100%;
}

body {
background-color: #DCDCDC;
margin: 0;
}

#menu li {
background: #DCDCDC;
display: inline-block;
list-style: none;
background-color: #B22222;
}

.listaArriba {
color: #000000;
width: 150px;
}

#titulua {
background-color: #000;
text-align: center;
margin-left: 300px;
margin-top: 7px;
}

.seccion1 {
background-color: white;
height: 749px;
width: 1350px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
}

#footer {
margin-top: 0px;
height: 40px;
background-color: #B22222;
}

#soundcloud {
margin-right: 40px;
margin-top: 3px;
}

.navigationFoot {
text-align: right;
}

#creditos {
font-size: 12px;
text-decoration: none;
}

a {
color: black;
}

#o {
margin-left: 250px;
float: top;
}
```

```html
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<header class="headerEnd">
    <div class="cabecera">
        <ul id="lista1">
            <a href="home.html" id="fotoEndi"><img src="endikasangroniz.png" id=titulua></a>
            <a href="../EndiIngles/endi.html" id="o"><img src="../Bandera/uk.png"></a>
            <a href="../EndiCastellano/endi.html"><img src="../Bandera/banderaEspana.png"></a>
            <a href="../EndiEuskera/endi.html"><img src="../Bandera/ikurrina.png"></a>

        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
<header class="header">
    <div class="menu" id="menu">
        <nav class="top-menu">
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li class="listaArriba" id="news"><a href="news.html">NEWS</a></li>
                <li class="listaArriba" id="conciertos"><a href="gigs.html">GIGS</a></li>
                <li class="listaArriba" id="videos"><a href="videos.html">VIDEOS</a></li>
                <li class="listaArriba" id="songs"><a href="music.html">MUSIC</a></li>
                <li class="listaArriba" id="lyrics"><a href="lyrics.html">LYRICS</a></li>
                <li class="listaArriba" id="store"><a href="https://endikasangroniz.bandcamp.com/"
                        target="_blank">STORE</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel">
        <div id="carousel-ejemplo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-ejemplo" data-slide-to="0"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-ejemplo" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
            </ol>

            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="http://tblla.com//assets/img/uploads/projects/Park-2-1350x750.jpg" alt="Stolen Kiss">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Stolen Kiss</h3>
                        <p>Second Videoclip</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="https://www.google.es/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjgrKfz0rHXAhXGuxQKHTIND8kQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftblla.com%2Fprojects%2Fwhistler-olympic-paralympic-village&psig=AOvVaw0r6S37FmTYsThpv3APS60M&ust=1510322169410306"
                        alt="One More Shot">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>One More Shot</h3>
                        <p>First Videoclip</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--controls carousel-->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-ejemplo" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previo</span>
            </a>

            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-ejemplo" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Siguiente</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <ul class="navigationFoot">
            <a id="n" href="https://es-es.facebook.com/EndikaSangroniz/" target="_blank"><img
                    src="../IconosRedes/iconoFacebook.png"></a>
            <a id="n" href="https://www.instagram.com/endikasangroniz/?hl=es" target="_blank"><img
                    src="../IconosRedes/iconoInsta.png"></a>
            <a id="n" href="https://endikasangroniz.bandcamp.com/" target="_blank"><img id="soundcloud"
                    src="../IconosRedes/bandcamp.png"></a>
        </ul>

    </div>
</header>
</body>
```

Espero que se pueda ejecutar como lo he puesto, si no se puede hacermelo saber y editaré el código.
Saludos.

Comment: Las imágenes del carousel trata de subirlas a algún banco de imágenes gratuito para que puedas colocar el link y se puedan visualizar

Comment: Pondré un par de imágenes cualquiera de google imagenes

Comment: @CamiloVasquez ya he editado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ejecuté tu código en mi entorno local y vi dos problemas:

1. Te falta agregar la hoja de estilos de bootstrap
2. Estabas repitiendo dos veces un contenedor con clase `carousel` lo cual está fuera de la estructura que debe tener el mismo.

He probado varias veces y funciona correctamente.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".carousel").carousel();

    var altura = $('.menu').offset().top;
    $(window).on('scroll',function(){
        if ( $(window).scrollTop() > altura ){
            $('.menu').addClass('menu-fixed');
        } else {
            $('.menu').removeClass('menu-fixed');
        }
    });
    $("#news").mouseover(function(){
        $("#news").css("background-color", "#800000");
        $("#a").css("color",black);
    });
    
    $("#conciertos").mouseover(function(){
        $("#conciertos").css("background-color", "#800000");
    });         
    
    $("#videos").mouseover(function(){
        $("#videos").css("background-color", "#800000");
    });
    
    $("#songs").mouseover(function(){
        $("#songs").css("background-color", "#800000");
    });             

    $("#lyrics").mouseover(function(){
        $("#lyrics").css("background-color", "#800000");
    });
    
    $("#store").mouseover(function(){
        $("#store").css("background-color", "#800000");
    });
    
    $(".listaArriba").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".listaArriba").css("background-color","#B22222");
    });
});
```

```css
.headerEnd{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#000000;
    height:100px;
}
#fotoEndi{
    margin-left: 100px;
}

@font-face{
    font-family: "TituloEndi";
    src: url("GameofBrush.ttf");
}
a:link{
    text-decoration:none;
    
}
a:visited{
    color: #000000;
}

#nombreEndi{
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    color: #8B0000; 
    font-family: "TituloEndi";
    font-size:40px;
}

.header{
    height:100px; width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.menu{
    height: 37px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #B22222; 
    color:#333; 
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow:0px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0)
}
.wrapper{ height:2000px; 
   width:100%; 
   padding-top:20px
}
.menu-fixed {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1000;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #999;
}
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block; 
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 100%;
}

body{
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    margin: 0;
}

#menu li{
    background: #DCDCDC;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    background-color:#B22222;
}

.listaArriba{
    color:  #000000;
    width: 150px;
}

#titulua{
        background-color:#000;
        text-align:center;
        margin-left: 300px;
        margin-top: 7px;
}

.seccion1{
    background-color: white;
    height:749px;
    width: 1350px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
#footer{
    margin-top:0px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color:#B22222;
}

#soundcloud{
    margin-right:40px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
.navigationFoot{
    text-align: right;
}
#creditos{
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a{
    color:black;
}
#o{
    margin-left: 250px;
    float: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<header class="headerEnd">
    <div class = "cabecera">
        <ul id = "lista1">
            <a href="home.html" id="fotoEndi"><img src="endikasangroniz.png" id=titulua></a>
            <a href="../EndiIngles/endi.html" id = "o"><img src="../Bandera/uk.png"></a>
            <a href="../EndiCastellano/endi.html"><img src="../Bandera/banderaEspana.png"></a>
            <a href="../EndiEuskera/endi.html"><img src="../Bandera/ikurrina.png"></a>
            
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
<header class = "header">
    <div class="menu" id="menu">
        <nav class="top-menu">
            <ul class = "navigation">
                <li class="listaArriba" id="news"><a href="news.html">NEWS</a></li>
                <li class="listaArriba" id="conciertos"><a href="gigs.html">GIGS</a></li>
                <li class="listaArriba" id="videos"><a href="videos.html">VIDEOS</a></li>
                <li class="listaArriba" id="songs"><a href="music.html">MUSIC</a></li>
                <li class="listaArriba" id="lyrics"><a href="lyrics.html">LYRICS</a></li>
                <li class="listaArriba" id="store"><a href="https://endikasangroniz.bandcamp.com/" target="_blank">STORE</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="carousel-ejemplo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-ejemplo" data-slide-to="0"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-ejemplo" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
        </ol>
        
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="http://tblla.com//assets/img/uploads/projects/Park-2-1350x750.jpg" alt="Stolen Kiss">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Stolen Kiss</h3>
                    <p>Second Videoclip</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://tblla.com//assets/img/uploads/projects/Park-2-1350x750.jpg" alt="One More Shot">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>One More Shot</h3>
                    <p>First Videoclip</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!--controls carousel-->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-ejemplo" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previo</span>
        </a>
        
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-ejemplo" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Siguiente</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <ul class = "navigationFoot">
            <a id="n" href="https://es-es.facebook.com/EndikaSangroniz/" target="_blank"><img src="../IconosRedes/iconoFacebook.png" ></a>
            <a id="n" href="https://www.instagram.com/endikasangroniz/?hl=es" target="_blank"><img src="../IconosRedes/iconoInsta.png"></a>
            <a id="n" href="https://endikasangroniz.bandcamp.com/" target="_blank"><img id="soundcloud" src="../IconosRedes/bandcamp.png"></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Camilo! Llevaba un buen tiempo dandole vueltas.